# Creating fractals (mandelbrot set) using math nodes

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine

I'm new to blender and I use hp elitebook 9470m which has i5 processor, recently I tried to make fractals on a single plane using script node which is basically only available in cycles render engine(using osl). When I tried to render a 180 frames of animation each frame took about 6 minutes to render, I searched for other ways. I realized that we can even do it in shader editor using math nodes.
But I'm stuck at the usage of nodes and it's iterations 
Can anyone help me how to complete this in which we can even zoom into fractals (I think iterations may require many nodes, but I seriously need this)

Comment: 6 minutes on this low-end machine is quite fast IMHO. If you can, I suggest share a file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/